# RegEx match entire word

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to catch all words that contains "**centimeters**", like:
**10.50centimeters** from this sentence "**This product have 10.50centimeters length..**".

my function:

```
function findMatchingWords(t, s) {
    var re = new RegExp("\\w*"+s+"\\w*", "g");
    return t.match(re);
}
findMatchingWords('This product have 10.50centimeters length..','centimeters');
```

but returns only "**50centimeters**". Is not getting the numbers before the dot.

Any help with this please?

Comment: Do you only need to match numbers?

Comment: No. Need to get both numbers and word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is not getting the numbers before the dot.

`\w` doesn't match a dot, it's equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. `[\w.]` would (or `[A-Za-z0-9_.]`).

```
var re = new RegExp("[\\w.]*"+s+"\\w*", "g");
```

Live Example:

```js
function findMatchingWords(t, s) {
        var re = new RegExp("[\\w.]*"+s+"\\w*", "g");

    return t.match(re);
}
console.log(findMatchingWords('This product have 10.50centimeters length..','centimeters'));
```

---

Side note: You'll want to escape characters with special meaning in `s` before feeding it to the `RegExp` constructor. [This question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) have functions to do that.